# How to update/refresh a specific item of RecyclerView without calling notifiyItemChanged or DiffUtil?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a nested `RecyclerViews` and each row/item of this recyclerView is a recyclerView too ,and there is an outer events will update an item in the inner recyclerView.
My onBindViewHolder of the outer RecyclerView adapter look like that

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            GiftWrappingHorizontalViewHolder viewHolder = (GiftWrappingHorizontalViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.giftWrappingRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(viewHolder.giftWrappingRecyclerView.getContext(),
                    RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));
            viewHolder.topTextView.setText(dataList.get(position).getTopTextName());
            if(dataList.get(position).getType() == 1) {
                GiftWrappingHorizontalAdapter adapter = new GiftWrappingHorizontalAdapter(dataList.get(position)
                        .getItems(), position);
                viewHolder.giftWrappingRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                viewHolder.giftWrappingRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
                adapter.setGiftWrappingHorizontalClickListener(giftWrappingHorizontalClickListener);
            } else if(dataList.get(position).getType() == 0){
                GiftWrappingAddOnsAdapter adapter = new GiftWrappingAddOnsAdapter(dataList.get(position)
                        .getItems(), position);
                viewHolder.giftWrappingRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                viewHolder.giftWrappingRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
                adapter.setGiftWrappingAddOnEventsListener(giftWrappingAddOnEventsListener);
            }

    }
```

So as you can see I'm binding the inner recyclerViews to its adapters inside the onBindViewHolder
and I want to update a specific item of the inner recyclerView without calling notifiyItemChanged because this will recreate the inner adapters which is paginated and it will call for the first page only because the inner RecyclerViews are using HORIZONTAL LinearLayoutManager .

Is there any to achieve that by accessing an item of the recyclerView by its position and call notifiyItemChanged to the inner RecyclerView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with [**`notifyItemChanged()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

```
notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)
```

> Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed
>   with an optional payload object.

LOGIC

```
arrayList.set(updatePosition, yourValue);
adapterOBJ.notifyItemChanged(updatePosition);
```

Comment: but this will recall onBindViewHolder and recreate the adapter object and only first page of the inner API will be called...what if the update was to item in the third page?

Comment: you mean using it with payload will do the trick ... do have any full example about using notifyItemChanged with payload ?

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery yes. Read https://medium.com/@MiguelSesma/update-recycler-view-content-without-refreshing-the-data-bb79d768bde8

Answer (score 0):

[LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java)

Fun part is you can use it directly in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="myTextLiveData" type="String" />
    </data>

    <TextView
    ...
      android:text="@{myTextLiveData}
    />

</layout>
```

In adapter onBind() you can set livedata of the object and wherever you update livedata.setValue("new value"), it'll reflect immediately.

I strictly assume you're updating data portion only. If your data is going to modify order or list size then better stick to notifyItemChanged()

You could also consider [DiffUtil](https://blog.mindorks.com/the-powerful-tool-diff-util-in-recyclerview-android-tutorial)